# A última instrução de um switch precisa de 'break'?

Tags: java, switch

Estava assistindo alguns tutoriais no YouTube e notei que alguns programadores deixam a última instrução de um bloco `switch` sem a palavra `break`. Por exemplo:

```
switch(frutas){
   case "abacaxi": abacaxi++; break;
   case "morango": morango++; break;
   case "pera": pera++; // sem 'break' aqui...
}
```

Achei interessante, de principio pensei que era só *Programming style*. Eu sempre utilizo `break` mesmo na última instrução, mas após ver os vídeos percebi que não há necessidade visto que ela é a última do bloco. Pelo que eu sei, o `break` serve (me corrijam se estiver errado) justamente para interromper uma instrução.

Gostaria se essa prática pode levar a algum problema.

Comment: Se você resolver inserir mais um `case` no final e esquecer de colocar o `break` no anterior, pode sim dar problema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Diretamente não há problema a não ser de confusão durante a manutenção conforme o bfavaretto colocou no comentário dele.

Eu não tenho muito a dizer sobre, exceto que é opção estilística de codificação. Diga-se de passagem, bem ruim se resolver seguir esse pessoal.

O problema desses tutoriais e informações postadas onde não se dá devida importância para a qualidade do conteúdo, como acontece muito pela internet e em muitas ocasiões aqui mesmo, é que na tentativa de ajudar as pessoas com a melhor das intenções, as pessoas que fazem e defendem a informação sem um amplo contexto está prestando um desserviço na formação dos programadores que buscam se beneficiar destas informações.

O que você pode fazer não é o mesmo do que você deve fazer. Alguns programadores só se preocupam se o programa funciona ou não. Outros se preocupam se ele está certo ou não, se ele vai continuar funcionando ou não, se ele dará facilidades de manutenção ou não.

Continue fazendo o certo que você sempre fez, mesmo que funcione do jeito novo que aprendeu. E sempre que tiver dúvida, pergunte em um local confiável. Se tudo correr bem, se eu falei alguma besteira, alguém vai postar algo melhor ou vai me corrigir. Torna o processo mais confiável.

Só para ser mais preciso o `break` interrompe um bloco de instruções.